# Open directory, external NFS file shares and automounter

Tags: mac-osx-server, opendirectory, autofs, home-directory

This may be a big one.

I've set up Open Directory on Mac OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion) with users to allow everyone on the network to logon to any client with these centrally stored users.

Before this system, we used NIS and mounted home directories with automounter (autofs). That was easy to setup as the NIS host and the fileserver was on the same box.

Now, I need help with the home directories. The users on the Open Directory server needs their home directories from the external fileserver, and these home directories need to be mounted with automounter.

The home directories are exported as NFS shares, and the fileserver has the old autofs maps. I just don't know where to go from here.

Any help or links to documentation would be appreciated. Finding documentation on the Open Directory services on Mac OSX 10.8 is hard to come by

EDIT: As far as I've been able to read, the nis maps need to be added to the LDAP directory in the Open Directory. I've found a guide for OSX 10.7, but so much has changed since then.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm struggling with something similar now.

Comment: Nope, no luck. It is strange to me that a login server for all platforms have not been made. It shouldn't be much trouble. With this specific issue, I'm guessing that Apple only allows for their own way of sharing folders